# Oracle ODBC Driver - Access denied after oracle update

Tags: odbc

we've updated an oracle database to oracle production version 19.11.0.0.0, the client version is 11.2.0.3.0. The ODBC Driver is: Oracle in OraClient11g_home1

If we are going to connect to the database, we got the following error:

```
SQLState=2800
[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-010107: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Login with sqlplus wqorks fine.

tsnames.ora and everything looks fine, it worked until we updated the oracle version. Does anyone have an idea, what's the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep with the 11.2 client, dig into the `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT` setting, see the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/netrf/parameters-for-the-sqlnet.ora.html#GUID-B2908ADF-0973-44A9-9B34-587A3D605BED).
I see there's a bit of background [in this doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/spucs/check-for-sqlnet-allowed-logon-version-parameter-behavior.html#GUID-433E0DB9-026E-4322-A8FF-BA0E108AB28B) and [this post](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4313265/11-2-0-2-0-client-connecting-to-19c-gets-ora-01017-unless-it-has-a-10g-password); googling will give more.

Overall, it would be better to upgrade the client version to 19.